# Не работает COPY в docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fastapi

Собираю docker-compose для проекта, но почему когда собираю отдельно образ бекенда, все копируется и образ запускается, но если образ бекенда собирается в docker-compose, что файлы не копируются в директорию

```
FROM python:3.11

RUN mkdir /fastapi_app

WORKDIR /fastapi_app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD gunicorn main:app --workers 4 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind=0.0.0.0:8000
```

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    container_name: "db"
    image: postgres:alpine3.18
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - custom
    env_file:
      - backend/.env
  app:
    build:
      context: /backend
    env_file:
      - backend/.env
    container_name: fastapi_app
    command:
     - alembic upgrade head
    ports:
      - 9999:8000
    depends_on:
      - db    
networks:
  custom:
    driver: bridge
```

Опыта работы с докером очень мало, практически нет, возможно ошибки есть и в других частях (Например, не правильно указываю директории), но проблему с тем, что файлы не копируются не знаю как решить.[image]

Comment: Меня смущает «16 hours ago» на скриншоте — вы точно-точно **собираете** образ в docker-compose, а не используете какую-то очень старую версию образа, собранную из какого-то старого докерфайла те самые 16 часов назад?

Comment: @andreymal И правда, почистил файлы докера и все начало копироваться, спасибо большое за помощь!